# Set variable of parent view in child view iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

viewA.h

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *foo;
```

viewB.m

```
viewAViewController *viewA = [[viewAViewController alloc] init];  
viewA.foo = @"str";

[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

the variable in the viewA never changes.

I don't know how to set a view variable from a another view, without storyboard or seque, programmatically, and then pop back to it.

Both views are table views and I want to populate viewA table cell detail with a selected vaule from viewB.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by parent and child? What is the relationship between the two controllers? One thing for sure, using alloc init to create a ParentViewController is undoubtedly wrong (it's creating a new instance, not getting the one you have).

Comment: the parent view pushes the child view with ChildViewController *childView = [[ChildViewController alloc] init];  [self.navigationController pushViewController:childView animated:YES]

Comment: It's not correct to call those controllers parent and child, they're more like siblings. If you log self.parentViewController in Child, you'll see that the parent is the navigation controller.

Comment: Okay, ill edit the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right way to do this is using delegates.

Define a delegate in B like this:

```
@protocol MyDelegate <NSObject>
- (void) updateData:(NSString*)str;
@end
```

Also add a member variable in B like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<MyDelegate> selectionDelegate;
```

Make A a delegate for our custom delegate like this:

```
@interface A : UIViewController <MyDelegate>
```

Then implement this function in that VC's .m file

```
- (void) updateData:(NSString*)str{
    self.foo = str;
}
```

You will also need to initialize the delegate variable when B is created to the instance of A.

Somewhere in A.m

```
B *b = [[B alloc]init];
b.selectionDelegate  = self;
```

Now in B you can call [self.selectionDelegate updateData:string]; whenever you are ready. 
Hope this helps

Comment: When i do this is get "Incompatible pointer types initialized "ParentViewController *" with an expression of type "UIViewController"

Comment: So the parentView in this case is the Navigation Controller.  I just want to change the view of another controller that got pushed onto the stack.  viewA pushed viewB, viewB change viewA variable and pop back.

Comment: so you didnt push viewB on viewA? sounds like that might have been better.. anyway you can also use presentingViewController and presentedViewController from ios5 onwards .. not sure what your app flow is but hopefully you understand what you need to do .. find the instance of the VC under the current one and update that guy's variable

Comment: Okay thanks.  I did push viewB onto viewA.  From viewA i called the push to viewB function.  In viewB i will access viewA's variable, change it, and pop back.  Sound right?

Comment: @user2891803, the usual way to do this is with delegation. viewA sets itself as the delegate of viewB when it creates viewB. viewB defines a delegate protocol (which viewA implements) and calls the delegate method at the appropriate time.

Comment: I agree with rdelmar.. Ideally b should not need to know about the structure of a.

Comment: Could you point me in the right direction for some tutorial or material to read about delegation?